# Elegant way of getting mutliple input value in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not allow to post any picture? Here is it 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn0GD.png

The author used same event on onChange, then assign the update value into an object, then update the state.

So the render will be like this

```
<input id="username" onChange={this.updateComment.bind(this)} />
<input id="comment" onChange={this.updateComment.bind(this)} />
```

Any better way of doing this? this is smart to me, you don't have to set individual key, the id as the object key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/67497/

```
var localStore = {
   todo : Immutable.Map({username:'', comment: ''}),
   updatelocalStore : function(property, value){
     this.todo = this.todo.set(property, value);
     this.onChange();
   },
   onChange: function(){}
};


var MyForm = React.createClass({

 getInitialState(){
    return localStore.todo;
 },

 updateComment(id, e) {
    var value = e.target.value;
    localStore.updatelocalStore(id, value);
 },

 componentWillMount(){
    //console.log(this.state);
    localStore.onChange = () => this.setState({todo:localStore.todo},
        ()=>{
        const state = this.state;
        var username = state.todo.get('username');
        console.log(username);
      });
 },

  render() {
    return (
    <form>
        <input onChange={this.updateComment.bind(this,'username')} />
        <input onChange={this.updateComment.bind(this, 'comment')} />
    </form>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyForm />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: this approach is similar but it mutated the state. Correct me if I'm wrong. And I don;t know why you need an arrow function in setState.

Comment: You are right, but the arrow function is just informative to show in the console how the state change.